# Problem when installing pip for python 2.7.16 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: pip, python-2.7

I used the following in Home

```
$ sudo apt install python-pip
```

the output was the following

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-pip : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
              Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
              Recommends: python-all-dev (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-setuptools but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-wheel but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I already tried the following without sucess

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

no special output but didn't fix the problem

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

no special output but didn't fix the problem

`sudo apt-get -f install` after `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and then
`sudo apt-get -f install`

output was : `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.`

`sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade` and then `sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade`

which gave the output :  `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

The aforementioned were some of the solutions proposed here [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Thanx!! :)

Comment: I do not understand the connection with the question https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository.  Maybe its because am new in Ubuntu.
The solution proposed in https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages the output says there are too many packages which contain pip in their name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did

```
$ sudo apt install python-setuptools
```

and after

```
$ sudo apt install python-pip
```

and it solved the problem..